# Executing Maple Code Inside Mathematica

Tags: interoperability, maple

Is it possible to create a C++ program using [MathLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html) that will invoke the Maple kernel and execute a very basic Maple command using [OpenMaple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple)?

I'm envisioning the following:

```
Install["MapleLink"]
```

starts the external program MapleLink and installs the *Mathematica* definition RunMaple.

```
?RunMaple

RunMaple[expr] returns a string which is the output when Maple executes expression expr
```

A sample output:

```
RunMaple["seq(i, i=0..3);"]

"0, 1, 2, 3"
```

I'm also open to using [J/Link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html).

Comment: Should be quite possible, but I would rather use Java bindings. Cross-platform, higher-level, also JLink is much easier to use than MathLink - what's not to like?

Comment: I'm totally open to any solution. I'll edit the problem to reflect this.

Comment: out of curiosity what is your usage/application. (Why are you unable to just run the Maple code in Maple?)

Comment: I would find it convenient to access the output from some commands in the RegularChains package.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this James?  I am interested in using a few Maple functions inside Mathematica too.

Comment: I have not got around to putting it together yet. I can look into it this weekend for sure.

Comment: @JamesRohal Do you still use this and do you have an update that works with recent Mathematica / Maple / macOS versions?

Comment: @Szabolcs No, sorry. I have not used this for a while and do not have the latest versions of Mathematica or Maple to test it. Is there a particular step in the old solution that failed?

Answer (score 21):

**Begin Note:** I have successfully got this working in the following environments.

1. On a Mac PC running version 9.0.0.0 using a locally installed JRE (version 1.6.0_37).
2. On a Windows PC running version 9.0.0.0 using a locally installed JRE (version 1.7.0_13).

I found that on my Windows PC, the JRE included with *Mathematica* is version 1.6.0_10 and the method described below fails when initializing the Maple engine at this step:

```
MapleEngine = JavaNew[engineload, {"java"}, defaultexception, Null, Null]
```

> ```
> Java::excptn: "A Java exception occurred: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: "
> ```

So if you are getting the error seen above, try loading a newer version of Java when doing `ReinstallJava`. I show how to do this below.

You can find out the version of Java that *Mathematica* is running by executing the following.

```
Needs["JLink`"]
ReinstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.System"];
java`lang`System`getProperty["java.version"]
```

**End Note**

[Java OpenMaple](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/API) provides an interface between the Maple evaluation engine and a Java program. [J/Link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromMathematica.html#23811) provides *Mathematica* users with the ability to interact with arbitrary Java classes directly from the front end. The goal here is to use J/Link to access the methods from OpenMaple. It is assumed that Maple is installed on the computer you are doing this on.

First, load J/Link.

```
Needs["JLink`"]
```

We will refer to the location of the Maple installation as `MAPLEDIR` and the location of the Java OpenMaple native library as `BINDIR` as per [this example](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Examples). You can find these locations by executing, `kernelopts(mapledir);` and `kernelopts(bindir);` in Maple, respectively. The images below show the outputs in Windows and OS X, respectively.

[image: kernelopts(mapledir) and kernelopts(bindir) in Maple in Windows]

[image: kernelopts(mapledir) and kernelopts(bindir) in Maple in OS X]

Here are the directories from my Windows and Mac machine, respectively.

```
(* Windows *)
MAPLEDIR = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Maple 16";
BINDIR = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Maple 16\\bin.win";
(* OS X *)
MAPLEDIR = "/Library/Frameworks/Maple.framework/Versions/16";
BINDIR = "/Library/Frameworks/Maple.framework/Versions/16/bin.APPLE_UNIVERSAL_OSX";
```

Add the Java OpenMaple components to the class path.

```
(* Windows *)
AddToClassPath[MAPLEDIR <> "\\java\\externalcall.jar"];
AddToClassPath[MAPLEDIR <> "\\java\\jopenmaple.jar"];
(* OS X *)
AddToClassPath[MAPLEDIR <> "/java/externalcall.jar"];
AddToClassPath[MAPLEDIR <> "/java/jopenmaple.jar"];
```

Update the environment variables.

```
(* Windows *)
oldPATH = "PATH" /. GetEnvironment["PATH"];
SetEnvironment["PATH" -> oldPATH <> ";" <> BINDIR];
(* OS X *)
SetEnvironment["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> BINDIR];
SetEnvironment["MAPLE" -> MAPLEDIR];
```

Since `SetEnvironment` is new in 9, lower versions should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003481/131301).

Now that we are done with the set up, we will launch the Java runtime. As per the **Note** above, I launch the local version of Java in Windows and use the built-in version of Java in OS X.

```
(* Windows *)
ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe"]
(* OS X *)
ReinstallJava[];
```

Next, create a default instance of a class implementing the [EngineCallBacks](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple%2fJava%2fEngineCallBacks) interface.

```
exceptionload = LoadJavaClass["com.maplesoft.openmaple.EngineCallBacksDefault"]
defaultexception = JavaNew[exceptionload]
```

> ```
> JavaClass[com.maplesoft.openmaple.EngineCallBacksDefault, <>]
> « JavaObject[com.maplesoft.openmaple.EngineCallBacksDefault] »
> ```

Next, create an instance of [Engine](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Engine) to start the Maple session. Only one Engine can be created during a single run of the JVM, even after the Engine has been stopped.

```
engineload = LoadJavaClass["com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine"]
MapleEngine = JavaNew[engineload, {"java"}, defaultexception, Null, Null]
```

> ```
> JavaClass[com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine, <>]
> « JavaObject[com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine] »
> ```

In Windows, if the Maple kernel gets initialized, then the following splash screen briefly appears. (This did not show up in OS X.)

[image: Maple splash screen in Windows]

Using `MapleEngine`, you can now perform computations using [evaluate](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Engine/evaluate). Depending on what the input is, the object returned by evaluate differs.

```
out = MapleEngine@evaluate["seq(i, i=0..3);"];
```

> ```
> « JavaObject[com.maplesoft.openmaple.Expseq] »
> ```

In this example, the method returns an [Expseq](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Engine/newExpseq) object. However, [Algebraic](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Algebraic) is the base class for every Java OpenMaple class that represents a Maple object. Since Expseq publicly inherits from Algebraic, we can use methods from Algebraic to study it. First, we load the Algebraic class.

```
algebraicload = LoadJavaClass["com.maplesoft.openmaple.Algebraic"]
```

> ```
> JavaClass[com.maplesoft.openmaple.Algebraic, <>]
> ```

Now we can manipulate our output `out`.

```
out@algebraicload`toString[]
```

> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3]
> ```

Here, `out` has head `String`.

You can create persisting variables using the [newName](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/Engine/newName) method. We assign the value 100 to the variable `abcde` and then add 5 to it.

```
name = MapleEngine@newName["abcde", True];
name@assign[MapleEngine@newNumeric[100]];
out = MapleEngine@evaluate["abcde + 5;"];
out@algebraicload`intValue[]
```

> ```
> 105
> ```

There is a lot more you can do if you take a look at the [Java OpenMaple API](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/category.aspx?cid=1851). The code above is only a starting point. I can imagine someone building a nice package off of this.

Comment: Excellent!  If you make a small package out of this, could you please put it on GitHub for easier collaboration?

Comment: I definitely will.

Comment: I think Mathematica doesn't include Java on OS X so we're free to install whichever version we'd like to use.  (It does indeed include 1.6u10 on Windows).  Thanks for the hints on getting it working on Win!

Comment: What I'm actually interested in is transferring large integers (larger than machine integers). Actually transferring a list of them. Is the best way just using a string?

Comment: Oh, I did not know it did not include it. I will make that change. In regards to the large integers, I think a string may be your best bet. A quick search on "max length of Java strings" brings up a result saying strings can be no
longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE (in excess of two billion) characters. OpenMaple supports strings via MString: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=OpenMaple/Java/MString

Comment: I'm not sure if you knew that this site has a [blog](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com).  If you feel like expanding this a little bit, making it into a tutorial and showing a practical application, it would make a nice blog post.  If you feel interested, drop me an [e-mail](http://i.stack.imgur.com/STOQ5.png)!

Answer (score 5):

I have upvoted both the question and the excellent answer by James Rohal. In his answer James mentioned only Windows and macOS, but when I tried to run this code on Linux, it did not work out of the box. It took me a while to figure out what was the problem. Apart from the obvious replacement `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH -> LD_LIBRARY_PATH` I also had to specify the `CLASSPATH` two times: when executing `ReinstallJava` and as a separate environmental variable. Here I would like to provide my working Linux code for the benefit of other Linux users. Since Linux was not mentioned in the original answer by James, I hope that this is fine.

The following has been tested with Fedora 28 (64-bit), Mathematica 11.3 and Maple 2015. My Maple distribution is located in `/media/Data/Software/maple2015`. The Java version is 1.8.0_172 from Oracle.

```
<< JLink`

MAPLEDIR = "/media/Data/Software/maple2015";
BINDIR = FileNameJoin[{MAPLEDIR, "bin.X86_64_LINUX"}];
CLASSDIR = FileNameJoin[{MAPLEDIR, "java"}];

SetEnvironment["MAPLE" -> MAPLEDIR];
SetEnvironment["LD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> BINDIR];
SetEnvironment["CLASSPATH" -> FileNameJoin[{CLASSDIR, "*"}]];

ReinstallJava[CommandLine -> "/usr/bin/java", ClassPath -> CLASSDIR]

exceptionload = 
 LoadJavaClass["com.maplesoft.openmaple.EngineCallBacksDefault"]
defaultexception = JavaNew[exceptionload]
engineload = LoadJavaClass["com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine"]

MapleEngine = 
 JavaNew[engineload, {"java"}, defaultexception, Null, Null]

out = MapleEngine@evaluate["seq(i, i=0..3);"];

algebraicload = LoadJavaClass["com.maplesoft.openmaple.Algebraic"]

out@algebraicload`toString[]
```

[image]

Comment: I have problems in using this. When running the command: MapleEngine = JavaNew[engineload, {"java"}, defaultexception, Null, Null] I encountered an error: JavaNew::fail: Error calling constructor for class com.maplesoft.openmaple.Engine. Do you know why?

Comment: There was a `"];` missing in `MapleEngine@evaluate` (it is correct in the screenshot, though), but apart from that everything works for me with Mma 12.1 and Maple 2020.