# Automatic import of Maple expressions into Mathematica using MathML

Tags: import, maple

I'm would like to automate a process so as to convert Maple expression into *Mathematica* expression.

For the moment, thanks to the function `MathML:-ExportContent(expr)` in Maple and the function `ImportString[mml, "Expression"]`, I manage to make this conversion.

**Maple code:**

```
 expr:=a=1/2*m*x^2:
 MathML:-ExportContent(expr);
"<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'><apply 
id='id8'><eq/><ci id='id1'>a</ci><apply id='id7'><times/><cn 
id='id2' type='rational'>1<sep/>2</cn><ci id='id3'>m</ci><app\
ly id='id6'><power/><ci id='id4'>x</ci><cn id='id5' 
 type='integer'>2</cn></apply></apply></apply></math>"
```

***Mathematica* code:**

```
mml = "<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>\
\[IndentingNewLine]<apply id='id8'>\[IndentingNewLine]<eq/>\
\[IndentingNewLine]<ci id='id1'>a</ci>\[IndentingNewLine]<apply \
id='id7'>\[IndentingNewLine]<times/>\[IndentingNewLine]<cn id='id2' \
type='rational'>1
      <sep/>2
    </cn>\[IndentingNewLine]<ci \
id='id3'>m</ci>\[IndentingNewLine]<apply \
id='id6'>\[IndentingNewLine]<power/>\[IndentingNewLine]<ci \
id='id4'>x</ci>\[IndentingNewLine]<cn id='id5' type='integer'>2</cn>\
\[IndentingNewLine]</apply>\[IndentingNewLine]</apply>\
\[IndentingNewLine]</apply>\[IndentingNewLine]</math>";
ImportString[mml, "Expression"]
```

However, I have to copy the MathML code that I have generated in Maple and copy it in a cell in a notebook in *Mathematica*.

For one expression, it is OK. But, I would like to make a process so as as to retrieve more expressions at the same time and with a less handy process.

Do you have some ideas so as to export the MathML code generated in Maple directly in *Mathematica*?

For example, retrieving some variables in *Mathematica* like the variable mml which gives the MathMl may be interesting for me.

Comment: This is relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11777/executing-maple-code-inside-mathematica

Comment: @Szabolcs For me, this solution is a bit complex since I didn't use C++. Is there a possibility without using C++?

Comment: I'm guessing this requires the Frontend to import mathml code?  If it doesn't it should be as easy as scripting with mathscript otherwise using the frontend will be a little trickier but I have done something like this.